# Concat two jsonb/json fields yields error

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

Trying to concat two json text fields like so:

```sql
SELECT app->>'id' || app->>'version' as foo
FROM table,
    json_array_elements(applications::json) as app;
```

Where `applications` is the data type text, results in the error:

```
LINE 3: SELECT app->>'id' || app->>'version' as foo
                                ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I've also tried with jsonb. What is happening here, and how should json text fields be concatenated together?

Comment: You just need to cast the values to the appropriate data types. Try something like this

SELECT (app->>'id')::text || app->>'version' as foo

Comment: If the column`applications` really contains JSON values, it should be declared as a `jsonb` column so that you don't need to cast it every time you want to do something useful with it.

Comment: You  have a precedence problem.  Your expression is interpreted as `(app->>'id' || app)->>'version'`.  Add explicit parentheses to clarify the order of the operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `||` binds stronger than the `->>` operator, so your expression is evaluated as `app ->> ('id'||app) ->> 'version'`

Enclose each expression in parentheses to avoid this:

```
(app->>'id') || (app->>'version')
```